# memory allocation for 64 bit OS

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

memory is divided into two parts
1) some memory portion reserved for OS system processes
2) remaining memory for user processes.
32 bit  OS allocates 4GB memory for OS processes. like this how many memory space is allocated for 64 bit OS(memory space only for system processes i.e. OS processes). This question was asked me in interview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me how specific this question is to Windows. From a generic perspective 2<sup>32</sup> gives you ~4 billion i.e. 4GB. So 2<sup>64</sup> would give you 16 [exabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) (!)

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) for more info.

> A 64-bit register can store 264 (over 18 quintillion) different
>   values. Hence, a processor with 64-bit memory addresses can directly
>   access 264 bytes(=16 exbibytes) of byte-addressable memory.

Note the provisos re. the external buses. Just because the CPU registers are 64-bit wide it doesn't *necessarily* imply that the external buses will be the same width. Consequently the CPU and machine architecture together will determine the practical limitations. Note the section marked [Limitations of Practical Processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#Limitations_of_practical_processors).

Answer (score 0):

Really not that true after all.

Windows comes with more than just 1 kernel or variations.

For example there are Windows OSs on the market with a kernel with PAE support, this is enough to demonstrate that your statement is not true.

Also 32 bit desktop versions of Windows are not capable to provide 4Gb of addressable memory but only ~3.5 .

**edit**
refer to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for detailed informations.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum memory address space is depending on the OS version that you have.

See [Physical Memory Limits: Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)

Some more reading on this in [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Physical Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx) and [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx)

Comment: you can have 4gb installed on a 32 bit Windows 7 but you will never be able to use 4gb with any process under a 32 bit Windows. That table refers to physical limits it's not about the limits imposed to each and every process.

Comment: @user1802174 I think OP's question in the interview has been not formulated very well. I guess he should have answered, "a lot more, but it fully depends on the OS and the CPU architecture"